# Access a Property of a Subclass

Tags: java, inheritance, compiler-errors, iteration

I'm quite new to Java, and am struggling to see why I keep getting an error at the command line. I have a superclass, Guest, with variables guestID, fName, lName and dateJoin. I also have a subclass VIPGuest with the additional variables VIPstartDate and VIPexpiryDate.

I have an ArrayList guests, which holds all the guest objects that I have in my records. I want to iterate through the ArrayList and write each Guest to a text file, with each Guest on a new line in the form guestID, fName, lName, dateJoin separated by commas(or guestID, fName, lName, dateJoin, VIPstartDate, VIPexpiryDate if the Guest is a VIPGuest).

My code is below. It works fine when I use similar code to do a similar thing for an ArrayList of objects of a class with no subclasses, but when I try and get it to work around the fact that some Guests have extra variables, the error is:

```
  HotelImpl.java:440: error: cannot find symbol
                    + "," + g.getVIPstartDate() + "," + g.getVIPexpiryDate());
                             ^
      symbol:   method getVIPstartDate()
      location: variable g of type Guest
    HotelImpl.java:440: error: cannot find symbol
                    + "," + g.getVIPstartDate() + "," + g.getVIPexpiryDate());
                                                         ^
      symbol:   method getVIPexpiryDate()
      location: variable g of type Guest
    2 errors
```

I can see that it's having trouble with the extra variables for VIPGuest objects, but I thought I'd fixed that with the if/else:

```
  public boolean saveGuestsData(String guestsTxtFileName){
    BufferedWriter writer;
    try{
      writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(guestsTxtFileName));
    } catch (IOException e){
      System.out.print("Invalid file.");
      return false;
    }
      try{
            for (Guest g : guests){
              if (!(g instanceof VIPGuest)){
                writer.write(
                g.getGuestID() + "," + g.getFName() + "," + getLName() 
                + "," + g.getDateJoin());

              }
              else {
                writer.write(
                g.getGuestID() + "," + g.getFName() + "," + 
                getLName() + "," + g.getDateJoin() + "," + 
                g.getVIPstartDate() + "," + g.getVIPexpiryDate());
              }
              writer.newLine();

            }
          writer.close();
          return true;
          } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.print("File not found.");
            return false;
          } catch (IOException e){
            System.out.print("Invalid file.");
            return false;
          }
  }
```

Comment: `g` is a Guest, not a VIPGuest. If you want to use the methods on the VIPGuest class, you need to cast `g` to VIPGuest -- eg. `((VIPGuest)g).getVIPstartDate()`

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you :)

Comment: @Habilee I recommend you to use an IDE, it will explain you this type of error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`g` is a reference of type `Guest`, so you can only access `Gusest`'s members from it. If you want to access `VIPGuest`'s members, you'll have to explicitly downcast it. E.g.:

```
VIPGuest vg = (VIPGuest) g;
writer.write(g.getGuestID() + "," + 
             g.getFName() + "," + 
             g.getLName() + "," +
             g.getDateJoin() + "," + 
             vg.getVIPstartDate() + "," + 
             vg.getVIPexpiryDate());
```

This should work, but it's a bad design, it forces your `saveGuestsData` method to have intimate knowledge of your `Guest` implementations. A more robust design is to move this logic to the `Guest` classes, and have this method just call them:

```
public class Guest {
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getGuestID() + "," + getFName() + "," +  getLName() + "," + g.getDateJoin();
    }

    // other methods...
}

public class VIPGuest extends Guest {
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return super.toString() + ", " + getVIPstartDate() + "," + getVIPexpiryDate());

    // other methods...
}
```

And then just call this method:

```
for (Guest g : guests) {
    writer.write(g.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In this answer I assume that `VIPGuest` extends `Guest`.

Before you can use any of the `VIPGuest` methods on a regular `Guest`, you need to cast the Guest to a VIPGuest.

```
for (Guest g : guests){
  if (!(g instanceof VIPGuest)){
    // omitted for brevity
  } else {
    VIPGuest vip = (VIPGuest)g;
    writer.write(vip.getGuestID() + "," + vip.getFName() + "," + vip.getLName() + "," + 
                 vip.getDateJoin() + "," + vip.getVIPstartDate() + "," + vip.getVIPexpiryDate());
  }
  writer.newLine();

}
```

While you know -- through your use of the `instanceof` check -- that `g` is actually a VIPGuest, the reference you have to it is only of a Guest.

Note that if `g` were not actually an instance of `VIPGuest`, the attempted cast `(VIPGuest)g` would likely throw a ClassCastException.

Comment: Right.  I was about to post a similar answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `g` is of type `Guest` and allthough the instance is a `VIPGuest`, the method `getVIPstartDate` is not available.

What you should do is:

```
else
{
  VIPGuest vg;
  vg = (VIPGuest)g;
  writer.write(
    vg.getGuestID() + "," + vg.getFName() + "," + 
    getLName() + "," + vg.getDateJoin() + "," + 
    vg.getVIPstartDate() + "," + vg.getVIPexpiryDate());
}
```

Even better:

Override the method `toString()` in both `Guest` and `VIPGuest`.
The latter calls `super.toString()` and adds the additional information.